# Mysql Host information not showing using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm following php/mysql tutorial book. The sample script connects me to my mysql database doesn't show what it should.

The line in question is

```
("Host information: %\n", mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
```

There rest of the code

```
 <?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Im not pasting this", "or this");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    } else {
        printf("Host information: %\n", mysqli_get_host_info());
}
?>
```

I just i get "Hostname: " on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your mysqli object in `mysqli_get_host_info()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-host-info.php. Try this code:

```
     <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* print host information */
printf("Host info: %s\n", $mysqli->host_info);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```